Windows 11. Number of duplicate entry's $Path variable
Why are the so many C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM entry's in the $PATH variable? I deleted them all except for 1 but after a while they are back again.... Only 1 is necessary. Not 8!!
Path variable
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  %SystemRoot%\system32\WBEM;
2  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
3  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
4  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
5  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
6  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
7  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
8  C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;
9  C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
10 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
11 C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
12 C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
13 C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;
14 C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
15 C:\WINDOWS\system32;
16 C:\WINDOWS;
17 C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
18 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
19 C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
20 C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
21 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;


Some application installer is inserting them. Is your machine part of a corporate network? Likely, assets are managed through WBEM. "WBEM is an industry initiative to develop a standard technology for accessing management information in an enterprise environment." https://www.ans.co.uk/docs/operatingsystems/windows/commonissues/wbem/ Check if IT keeps reinstalling management software on the PC. There are two PATH variables, and likely the app is being installed by the wrong user (ordinary user vs. Admin), so it keeps looking in the wrong PATH and adds to the other.

No. It's not a corporate machine. Just a private machine with a private network. The only IT involved here is me. Your suspicion can be true if during an installment of software it just adds it to the current path. Than it is just a bad case of programming not looking if that part of the path isn't there already. I can find out by looking at the path before and after the installment and compare them to see who is responsible for this mindless adding it to my path.  I will make a script who compares the two settings before and after. Thanks for the thought.

That script should work well, or you might use Nirsoft's RegistryChangesView , https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html, since both PATH variables are there. BTW. look for changes made app management software, e.g., NetBackup.
